# Update table structure without rollback in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1, rollback, migrate

I am beginner in Laravel. I use migrate to create tables in a database, but I don't want to `migrate:rollback` to update my table.

I want to apply changes in my old database without loosing current data.

#### Old migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

#### New migration

```
   public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('family');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: backup your data. Like dumping the sql

Comment: Laravel does not have any update migration command so take a backup of your data and rollback migration..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible and not the intention of migrations. I think there are two options to solve this:

1. If you aren't in production, you can change the migration script and add the additional column manually using mysql:

   ```
   alter table users add column family varchar(255);
   ```
2. If you need to update a productive database, you should add a second migration script only adding the additional column, e.g.:

   ```
   public function up()
   {
       Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
       {
           $table->string('family')->after('user_id');
       });
   }

   public function down()
   {
       Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
       {
           $table->dropColumn('family');
       });
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that by running a new migration file for instance in this case

```
php artisan migrate:make add_family_to_users
```

And by that, a new migration file will be created and you can add the family column to it together with the properties. Regarding the position, you can use the

> ->after('column name ')

to specify where the newly created column will precede. For instance, in your case, it would look something similar to this

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) 
{
        $table->string('family')->after('name');
});
```

lastly, re-run `php artisan migrate` and check in your table if the column has been added.